# rails ActiveStorage non-image document open in new browser tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

The following command
`<%= link_to image_tag(url_for(document.file.preview(resize_to_limit: [250, 250]))), document.file, disposition: :inline , target: '_document' %>` is launching the download of an ActiveStorage managed attachment.

The class is defined as:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
```

while the downloading functionality is of interest, the goal is to have the UI allow the visitor to view the PDF in a separate browser tab.  How can this be achieved?

**update**
*Note: in extracting `url_for(document.file).split('?').first`, the url to the document is obtained; pasting that into a new browser tab also initiates a download.*

Answer (score 1):

Probably `target="_blank"` and inline disposition is what you need

```
<%= link_to 'View in new tab', rails_blob_path(document.file, disposition: 'inline'), target: '_blank' %>
```

Comment: that has no consequence, whatever the string the download is activated (the browser is agnostic to the string, just that each string would represent a tab with that identifier).

Comment: @Jerome I've added disposition key

Comment: no, that's not it.  it was attempted originally.